# Please configure a TransactionTemplate on the transacted policy

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I implement a Spring Boot (1.5.x) application with Apache Camel (2.19)

For integration purposes I need to use three data sources (see for more about multi-data-sources here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources).

One of the routes I have marked with `.transacted()`:

```
        from(Consts.DIRECT_ROUTE + routeId)
        .routeId(routeId)
        .startupOrder(loadRouteParameters.getStartupOrderTransformAndLoad())
        .autoStartup(true)
        .transacted()
```

however, when I start the app I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found 3 PlatformTransactionManager in registry. Cannot determine which one to use. Please configure a TransactionTemplate on the transacted policy.
```

How to handle it? How to fulfill "Please configure a TransactionTemplate". I was not able to find any example for this special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have multiple `TransactionManager` beans in your Spring context. Camel does not know which one to take. You have to help your Camel a bit.

Define a `SpringTransactionPolicy` and reference the `TransactionManager` to be used in the Camel route.

```
<bean id="txPolicyName" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="[yourTxManagerBeanId]" />
</bean>
```

Then you can set the policy as argument to your `transacted()` in the Camel route:

```
.transacted("txPolicyName") // txPolicyBeanId as String
```

Comment: yes, I have multiple (three) `TransactionManager`s.